# How Can I let 2 child components update the same parent property?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component

I have some products that I want to filter based on their category using checkboxes.

To do so, I have a parent component which passes the possible categories (e.g. A, B and C) to the child and keeps track of the checked/selected categories:

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <FilterCheckboxItem
    ref="Category"
    name="Category"
    :FilterOptions="CategoryOptions"
    v-model="FilteredCategories"
  />
</template>

<script>


export default {
    data(){
        return {
          FilteredCategories: [],
          CategoryOptions: ["A","B","C"]
         }
    }
</script>
```

And the child component looks like this (simplified):

**FilterCheckboxItem.vue**

```
<template>
<div
  v-for="FilterOption in FilterOptions"
>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :value="FilterOption"
    v-model="checked"
  />
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: {
     FilterOptions: {
      type: Array,
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: Array,
    },
 },

  emits: ['update:modelValue'],


  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const checked = ref([]);
    watch(checked, (newVal) => {
      emit('update:modelValue', newVal);
    });
    return { emit, checked };
  },

</script>
```

This works as intended.

However, when I would like to add the same child component again (for example 1 filterbutton in the normal menu and 1 in the mobile-menu) the arrays from the 2 childs are not aligned anymore. For example, I select Category "A" on the first child component, then the second child component is not updated properly (Category "A") will not be checked.

How can I make sure that the whenever I change something in the first child-component it updates the parent component but also makes sure that the second child-component is updated properly?

I would expect this to work since they are referred to the same v-model property.

[Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v-model in the parent, which exists in the Child component as `modelValue`, is not the same v-model used on the actual inputs which is `checked`.  When `checked` update you use a watcher to update the parent v-model. There's no equivalent code to update `checked` when the v-model updates, but there doesn't need to be. Just use `modelValue` as your v-model on the input. No need to have `checked` or a watcher at all.

**FilterCheckboxItem.vue**

```html
<template>
<div
  v-for="(FilterOption, index) in FilterOptions"
> 
  <label for="lname">{{FilterOption}}</label>   
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    :value="FilterOption"
    v-model="modelValue[index]"
  />
</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
    props: {
     FilterOptions: {
      type: Array,
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: Array,
    },
 },
}
</script>
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thank you for the response. This indeed solves the issue that the 2 child components reamain aligned and is something I tried. However, it induces another problem: The array is updated with True and False per index, instead of the actual values. As a result, whenever the CategoryOptions: ["A","B","C"]  from the parent are changing (e.g. it shrinks to ["A","C"], the index do not align anymore. Let's say that the B checkbox was checked in the child (index 1) and the parent Category Options changes to ["A","C"], then it will still register index 1 as true, which now corresponds to "C"

Comment: This is why I used the solution with emit earlier, since the Child keeps track of the actual values in the array instead of Booleans with indices. Would you know 1 solution that solves both challenges?

Comment: I would argue the solution never induced this problem as it's technically a separate problem/question unrelated to keeping the two child models synced.  Now _in addition_ you want to sync the parent v-model to the CategoryOptions array?  You never mentioned CategoryOptions can change.  Please show where and how that is done, as it may be possible to update FilteredCategories at the same time.

Comment: I agree, I marked your answer as the solution. However, I did not use this approach earlier because it was giving some issues with the dynamic FilterOptions array, but perhaps that is indeed another issue/question and I should have clarified it a bit more.  I modified your example a bit to show what I mean: The FilterOptions is here dynamic, since it depends on another filter (e.g. price filter). I posted the link to the Vue Playground at the bottom of the question.